# check or uncheck a angular ui grid dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is a UI grid entry for creating a check box dynamically,

```
 {
     field: 'defaultYn',
     displayName: 'DefaultYn',
     width: '10%',
     enableFiltering: false,
     cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.defaultYn" ng-click="grid.appScope.updateRow(row);"  ng-true-value="\'Y\'" ng-false-value="\'N\'">'
    }
```

Here in updateRow, need to update the check box value programatically,

```
 $scope.updateRow = function(row) {
  SweetAlertService.confirm('Are you sure?','', function(isConfirmed) {
    if (isConfirmed) {

    }else{
        /* deselect the check box, code not working
        row.entity.defaultYn= "Y";*/
    }
     });
```

Sweet Alert code section

```
confirm: function(title, message, callback) {
                  swal({
                    title: title,
                    text: message,
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#33414e',
                    confirmButtonTexColor: '#FFF;',
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel: true,
                    timer: 1500
                  },
                  function(isConfirm) {
                      callback(isConfirm);
                  });
                }
```

Here not able to set the UI grid selected row values check box programmatically.
 How can I enable or disable a checkbox in UI grid through angular js code.

Here is  the issue  http://plnkr.co/edit/Sd7Uk5yTkhPFnzrsDknp?p=preview.

Comment: Here is a working example. http://plnkr.co/edit/KUi5hWOfYdeuZ5ec1unQ?p=preview For enabling and disabling, use ng-disabled directive directly.

Comment: I am setting this value inside a call back function, may be thats  why check box value is not changing.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Yes, it seems because of the callback function. It will be good if you can create a plunkr link and replicate the issue.

Comment: Here is the working example http://plnkr.co/edit/Sd7Uk5yTkhPFnzrsDknp?p=preview. Setting value to Y in any case.

Comment: @SaiGiridhar have any clue why this not working ?

Comment: In the pluckr link, I don't think that you have replicated the issue. Please replicate the issue, then we can help.

Comment: I had replicated the changes in the above given plunker, there we cant set values of check box to Y.

Comment: Your are explicitly making  row.entity.employed = "N" and how can you expect it to be "Y"? I guess that your isConfimed value is always being true.

Comment: No isConfirmed value is true or false based on selection of Ok or Cancel. What ever value we set programmatically in that checkbox, that is not affecting .